# GPU Driver Crash

Tags: windows, drivers, crash, gpu, amd-radeon

I have recently bought a XFX Radeon HD 6570 GPU for my custom built computer. Everything works fine, except my GPU. When I try to play games, such as Skyrim or Portal 2, it crashes. For example, I can open Skyrim, get to the menu, click new game, get past the loading screen, but right after the loading screen, it locks up. But on Portal 2, I can play for 30 seconds, then it freezes, video and audio, but eventually unfreezes and I can play for 30 more seconds or so. This cycles until it eventually lead to a BSOD. On Skyrim, I've experimented with different settings, and got different results, such as the game locks up and crashes my computer, or just the game crashes to desktop, or it crashes and windows tells me my driver for my GPU crashed and successfully recovered, or the game freezes then goes back to normal for 2 seconds, then freezes again and repeats. I know something is wrong, I'm almost positive it has to do with the driver for my GPU. My desktop is at max resolution and I can play videos through VLC if GPU acceleration is off. If I turn on GPU acceleration, the video is very choppy.

Side Note: Windows recognizes my GPU as a Radeon HD 6770, when it should be the 6570. So, I'm not even sure I have the 6570, although I bought the 6570 and the box and card says 6570.

If you have anything you're confused about or you need any extra details, just let me know. I'll respond quickly. Any thoughts or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch at skyrimnexus that fixes ati performance and visual problems. It makes the game think you have a nvidia card. If that doesn't help then you can try and change the audio settings to something else because Skyrim has a big audio problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the required drivers? Use [this tool](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/auto_detect.aspx) by AMD to install the correct GPU drivers for your card, also make sure you have the latest version of the GPU drivers.